# Custom schematics in Angular/CLI 6.x builds without errors but I cannot use it to generate files

Tags: angular, angular-schematics

I've created a few schematics before, before Angular 6.0. The same steps I did in Angular 5.x now always leads to the error `schematic 'my-schematic' not found in collection @schematics/angular` when I try to generate some code on a hosting application (of Angular 6)?.

My setup (global Angular stuff):

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.0
Node: 8.11.1
OS: win32 x64

@angular-devkit/{architect, core, schematics} 0.6.0
@schematics/angular 0.6.0
rxjs 6.1.0
typescript 2.7.2
```

My steps:

1. Ran `schematics schematic --name=my-first-schematics`. So it creates a new schematics project with three sample schemas in it. Then I navigated into that new folder `cd my-first-schematics`.
2. Ran `npm run build`. It built without errors.
3. Ran `schematics .:my-first-schematics`. Result: Error `"my-first-schematics" not found in collection "."` I saw in some blogs that they performed this step without problems, though. I never used to run this command, and I'm not sure what it actually does, so I'll proceed assuming that this command isn't necessary after all.
4. Ran `npm link` so that I can use this new schematics collection in a new project.
5. In another prompt window, I created a new application: `ng new schematics-consumer`, then after the npm installs, `cd schematics-consumer`.
6. Ran `npm link my-first-schematics` so I now have access to that schematics library.
7. I navigated to `src/app` as that's where I want to generate my file.
8. Ran `ng g my-schematic -c my-first-schematics`. Resulted in error `Schematic "my-schematic" not found in collection "@schematics/angular"`. I specified a collection. Why is it not seeing my new collection, and it's still thinking that every schematic is in `@schematics/angular`?

So, I cannot generate anything with schematics. I did not modify anything in the default code generated by `schematics schematic name=my-first-schematics`.

Is there a new set of commands, procedures, etc. to create our own custom schematics? What steps am I missing? What else do I need to install? I'll provide more information if necessary.

At this time, there are no new guides or blogs on schematics, as 6.0 is only a few weeks old, so I'm assuming the old way should still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the issue is ultimately with `angular-cli`, see discussion: https://github.com/angular/devkit/issues/528#issuecomment-387415646

To get around this, you can set your default collection to your custom schematics:

```
ng config cli.defaultCollection my-first-schematics
```

Now you should be able to run `ng g my-schematic`.

If this does not work can you post the file list of your `my-first-schematics` directory?

Comment: That actually works. Thank you. That inserted `{"cli": "defaultCollection": "my-first-schematics" }}` into `angular.json`, so my guess is it's not a global setting, but per workspace.